# pass json array value to vb.net

Tags: ajax, json, vb.net

I have a json data array value name "datavalue" and trying to send this value to my webmethod. i try and search but i cannot get any answer to my questions so far and the more i search the more i. or maybe there is something wrong with my codes.

here is my ajax post:

```
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "WebService.asmx/GetValue",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: datavalue,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
                        if (!data.error) {
                            alert("Works!");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Error" + " " + data.error);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        alert('Error: ' + msg);
                    }
```

my datavalue:(i get this value thru firebug

```
datavalue = country_1=Singapore&city_1=Kathmandu&postal_code_1=sa&country_2=Singapore&city_2=Singapore&postal_code_2=sa&length_1=sa&width_1=sa&height_1=sa&weight_1=sa&length_2=&width_2=&height_2=&weight_2=&contact_name=f&contact_number=f&email=f&address=t&post_code=f&city=Singapore
```

and this is my webservice.

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetValue(ByVal datavalue As Object) As Object
    Return datavalue
End Function
```

im new in json and new in webservice.
thank you in advance

Comment: so whats the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i'm a bit unsure as to what is going wrong - but i'm guessing that your functions return value is nothing.

Instead of using an object as the parameter for your function, try using a list instead.

For example :

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetValue(values As List(Of String)) As List(Of String)
    Return datavalue
End Function
```

**Also**

Try setting the `traditional: true` setting in your ajax call. This will set the traditional param serialization.

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "WebService.asmx/GetValue",
                type: "POST",
                data: datavalue,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (msg) {
                    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
                    if (!data.error) {
                        alert("Works!");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Error" + " " + data.error);
                    }
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert('Error: ' + msg);
                }
```